# Is it possible to make nullable = true in a one to one relationship?

Tags: grails, grails-orm

The two domains are as follows:

```
class Face {

    static hasOne = [nose:Nose]

    static constraints = {
        nose unique: true

    }

}   


class Nose {
    Face face

    static constraints = {

    }
}
```

The foreign key will be in the Nose table. The Nose table has reference to Face table. The face_id column in Nose table is not nullable. I was wondering if it is possible to make this column nullable. I tried the following constraint variations but none of them seem to alter the structure of the tables.

class Face {

```
    static hasOne = [nose:Nose]

    static constraints = {
        nose unique: true
        nose nullable: true

    }

}


I also tried the following 

class Nose {
    Face face

    static constraints = {
        face nullable:true
    }
}
```

I need a one to one relationship between these two domains but also want to be able to create independent Nose or Face entities or records. Is that possible? If so, can you suggest a way? Thanks! Appreciate it!

Comment: You are on one side marking nose as unique if we say that it would be null in many cases then it breaks the constraint. Go for composition if you need that high flexibilty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a third relationship domain which would specify the relation between Face and Nose.

```
FaceNose{
   Face face
   Nose nose

   static constraint{
      nose nullable:false,unique:true
      face nullable:false,unique:true
   }
}


class Face {
//face class properties
    static constraints = {

    }

}   


class Nose {
    //nose class properties
    static constraints = {

    }
}
```

This fulfils your Need for one to one relationship with independent entries for both.

Answer (score -1):

With hasOne relationship, Grails creates "not null" foreign key.

```
class Face{
     ..
     static hasOne = [nose : Nose]
}

class Nose{
     Face face
}
```

creates "face_id" in the nose table with "not null" face_id.

Work around

```
class Face{
     ..
     static hasMany = [noses: Nose]
     static transients = ['getNose']

     Nose getNose{
         return this.noses[0] ?: null 
     }
}
```

face.nose      // this would work